# Select2 multi-value: How to refresh

Tags: select2-rails

I'm using ajax in Rails 4 to load this form.  Using select2-rails gem, it renders properly when the document loads:

[image]

After I click update, it loads the view partial:

[image]

but when I click on edit, the styling doesn't show up, and only the default bootstrap styling shows up:

[image]

How do I get this last image to show the select2 styling from the first image?  I think it has to do with how select2 styling is loaded when the document is first loaded, but would appreciate a solution.  Here is my stylesheet below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#e9").select2();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Allen:

Hello again by the way...

I had a similar problem in rails 4 and it had to do with turbolinks.

link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works

In your JS file change your document ready to the function name below, then add the two commands just below the function, which are also below.  This may be your issue as well because your page initially loads correctly, however when turbolinks is working, it tries to load only previously loaded files to quicken the load process and may skip your document ready function.  Let me know if this helps... (Jake - DBC).

`var select2Gem = function(){
  $("#e9").select2();
};`

`$(document).ready(select2Gem);
$(document).on('page:load', select2Gem);`